# How to use PIVOT clause over blank values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Sample data:

```
Data table1:
prodid  type location(there are more columns, just ignoring them for this example)
p001        t1      l1
p002        t1      l2
p003        t3      l1
p004        t2      
p005        t1      l1

Need a summary like
type    Blank [l1]  [l2]
t1      0           2           1
t2      1           0           0
t3      0           1           0
```

The problem am facing is with the blank values in the location field. I donno how to represent the blank location values in the pivot query.

```
Pivot query:
1: select type, [] as Blank, [l1], [l2], Blank + [l1] + [l2] as Total from
2: (select type, location from table1)
3: pivot 
4: (count(location) for location in ([],[l1],[l2]) t2

Error on line 1 & 4
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Add a name or single space as the alias name.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just swapping out the null/blank locations for a dummy value. So change

```
select type, location from table1
```

to

```
select type, CASE WHEN location is null THEN 'ZZ' ELSE location END as location from table1
```

Then the column will be zz or whatever dummy value you choose

Comment: I put CASE because I wasn't sure if your locations were empty strings or truly null. If they are null you can use isnull(location, 'zz') which should be a bit more efficient I think. Although if you don't have masses of data you won't notice.

Answer (score 1):

You could just abandon `PIVOT` and use

```
SELECT type,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN location = '' THEN 1
             END) AS Blank,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN location = 'l1' THEN 1
             END) AS l1,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN location = 'l2' THEN 1
             END) AS l2,
       COUNT(*)   AS Total
FROM   table1
WHERE location in ('','l1','l2')
GROUP  BY type
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Martin. Acutal table has more location values and they can change. when i know how to handle the blank values, I was planning to build some program structure to get the unique list and prepare the pivot sql and run to make it dynamic. I can do the same for the suggested query but it could get lengthy. Any thoughts?